# Particle revolving in a frustum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics

I came across a problem in analysing the motion of a particle revolving in a cone/frustum. We consider a particle that is projected with a velocity $V_o$ along the edge of the frustum. Now we try to calculate the components of its final velocity, i.e. $V_d$ (down the incline) and $V_p$ (perpendicularly outward of the plane ,as shown in the photo) after it has dropped down by a height $h$ . There is one pretty straightforward method to calculate the downward velocity component of the particle along the surface, i.e $V_d$, we conserve angular momentum about the axis considering the $V_p$ component and then use energy conservation to find the other component, i.e $V_d$ .

I had no problem in the above method. But if we notice , there is no force acting along the direction of $V_d$ other than $mgsin(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is the angle made by the incline with the horizontal, $\alpha = tan^{-1}(h/(R-r))$ . So $V_d$ component is accelerating with the constant rate $gsin(\alpha)$. So applying the third eqn of motion ,  $V_d^2 - 0^2 = 2gsin(\alpha)L$ , where $L$ is the slant length of the frustum, using this we get the value $V_d = (2gh)^{1/2}$ which is incorrect since the correct answer is $V_d = (2gh - V_o^2(R^2/r^2-1))^{1/2}$ using the method I described earlier.

So I don't know where I went wrong , probably in the part where I used $L$ as the displacement term in the eqn. It would be really helpful if someone could clarify.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in the following statement:

> there is no force acting along the direction of $V_d$ other than $mg\sin(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is the angle made by the incline with the horizontal, $\alpha = \tan^{-1}(h/(R-r))$ . So $V_d$ component is accelerating with the constant rate $g\sin(\alpha)$.

This is incorrect, because the $V_d$ direction is not constant as the particle moves.  This is akin to how if we write out Newton's Second Law in polar coordinates, we do not have $m \ddot{r} = F_r$, we have $m (\ddot{r} - r \dot{\phi}^2) = F_r$;  the second term arises because the radial unit vector $\hat{r}$ changes throughout the motion.

Specifically to your problem, let's work in spherical polar coordinates, where the origin is at the "point" of the cone.  What you're calling the "$V_d$ component" is then just the radial component of the position vector, the distance moved along the cone is given by the change in $r$, and we have $\theta = \pi/2 - \alpha = \text{const.}$ throughout the motion.  But [it can be shown that the acceleration vector in polar coordinates](https://dynref.engr.illinois.edu/rvs.html) is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\vec{a} &= (\ddot{r} - r \dot{\phi}^2 \cos^2\alpha ) \,\hat{e}_r  + (r \ddot\phi \cos\alpha
              + 2 \dot{r} \dot\phi \cos\alpha
              ) \,\hat{e}_{\phi} + (- r \dot{\phi}^2 \sin\alpha \cos\alpha) \,\hat{e}_{\theta}\end{aligned}
$$
(where I have used the fact that $\theta$ is constant.)  So the radial component Newton's Second Law will be
$$
-mg \sin \alpha = m a_r = m(\ddot{r} - r \dot{\phi}^2 \cos^2 \alpha) \neq m\ddot{r}
$$
and the particle does not undergo uniform acceleration in the radial direction unless $\dot{\phi} = 0$ or $\alpha = \pi/2$ (both of which cases I'm pretty sure you're uninterested in.)

Comment: I had to edit a bunch of notation on the fly when writing this answer (both because of your choice of $\alpha$ as the angle from the horizontal, and because of that page's use of the "math convention" for spherical polar coordinates).   It's possible that I missed a detail here and there, so take the precise form of these equations with a grain of salt.  I'm confident that this is where your error lies, though.